# Getting All keys from Apache Ignite cache from Java Thin client

Tags: java, caching, server, ignite

> Now i am using apache ignite 2.8.0.

```
  public void run(){  

        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
         c.put(i,s);  
        }}
```

> I was put all the values by above code, now i want to get all the keys in that cache, how can i get all the keys from java thin client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Scan Query](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#scan-queries) to do that. Scan the whole cache or on per partition basis. There's a [documentation on using queries](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/java-thin-client-sql) with thin client (it mostly concerns SQL, should [work with ScanQuery](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/java-thin-client-key-value#section-scan-queries) too).

The simplest one should be
`cache.query(new ScanQuery()).getAll(); // Returns a collection of key-value pairs`.

Comment: Actually i dont want to create any tables, i need to get all the keys from cahce simply, can you please share that statement line?

Comment: yeah , it's works fine. but i want key not a object, where i place getkey()?

Comment: Try calling it on each k-v pair.

Comment: try (QueryCursor cursor = (QueryCursor) c.query(new ScanQuery()).getAll()) {
           
            for (Cache.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : cursor)
                System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey());

Comment: it shows error : Link all references for a local rename (does not change references in 
 other files)

Comment: `getAll()` does not return `QueryCursor`, it will return `List`.